# Derivative of Norm Squared of the Riemann Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow

I am currently reading some lecture notes on Ricci flow and am not sure how the following identity is derived:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \bigg( g^{ij}g^{kl}g^{ab}g^{cd}R_{ikac}R_{jlbd} \bigg) = 2\bigg(R^{ij}g^{kl}g^{ab}g^{cd} + g^{ij}R^{kl}g^{ab}g^{cd}+g^{ij}g^{kl}R^{ab}g^{cd} +g^{ij}g^{kl}g^{ab}R^{cd}\bigg)R_{ikac}R_{jlbd} \:+\:2<Rm,\frac{\partial}{\partial t}Rm> $

I know there are identities for the time derivative of the Riemann tensor in general, but I don't quite follow how the author has gone from the time derivative to the right-hand side, could someone explain?

Comment: I think you have one excess $g^{ij}$ on the LHS and the first summand of the RHS - else sum convention doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I've corrected this.  Are you now able to see where the identity comes from?

Comment: Hang on, I've realised it now, you just apply the product rule repeatedly and the final term is due to the metric being symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the product rule repeatedly and use the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g^{ij}=2R^{ij}$.  The final term arises from the fact that the metric is a symmetric form.